# Unpacking a list from a function gives a list is not defined error

Tags: python, list, function, import, os.path

```
import os.path
import re
def request ():
    print ("What file should I write to?")
    file = input ()
    thing = os.path.exists (file)
    if thing == "true":
        start = 0
    elif re.match ("^.+.\txt$", file):
        stuff = open (file, "w")
        stuff.write ("Requests on what to add to the server.")
        stuff.close ()
        start = 0
    else:
        start = 1
    go = "yes"
    list1 = (start, file, go)
    return list1
start = 1
while start == 1:
    request ()
    (start, file, go) = list1
```

I try to return get list1 to return and unpack it in the loop so I can set variables that come after the while loop. Whenever I try and run this and enter "Thing.txt", I get `NameError: name 'list1' is not defined`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: list1 is function-scope variable and you reference it outside request function

Comment: However, I returned it. Doesn't that solve the problem?

Comment: if you assing the return value to a new variable, with program-scope, named list1, yes it will

Comment: You are returning `list1` and not assigning it to any variable when you call `request()`. This: `list1 = request ()`

Comment: and change this: `if thing == "true":` to `if thing:`, or `if thing == True:`. **True** is boolean whereas "true" is **string**

Comment: As a general note about the question: you could simplify to only have the barest minimal code to demonstrate the point.

Comment: list1 variable is define in the function request. So list1 is function level variable. You can not access function level variables outside function. 
Updated statement:- list1 = request ()

Comment: @Darkshadows: Actually, you should get rid of `thing`: it's only used once so there's no need to store it in a variable. So you can just do `if os.path.exists (file):`. Also, rather than `print(promptstring); file = input()` you can do `file = input(promptstring)`. Both these changes will make your code cleaner & easier to read. Finally, `file` is not a good name for a variable, since it shadows the built-in `file` type, which can lead to mysterious & frustrating bugs. Similarly, don't use `list` or `str` as a variable name.

Comment: Also, if `go` only takes the values of `"yes"` or `"no"` and `start`  only takes the values of `0` or `1` you should probably make them both Booleans, i.e. `True` or `False` - it's easier to read for experienced Python programmers, and slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python


import os.path
import re
def request ():
    print ("What file should I write to?")
    file = input ()
    thing = os.path.exists (file)
    # thing is a boolean variable but not a string, no need to use '=='
    if thing:
        start = 0
    elif re.match ("^.+.\txt$", file):
        stuff = open (file, "w")
        stuff.write ("Requests on what to add to the server.")
        stuff.close ()
        start = 0
    else:
        start = 1
    go = "yes"
    list1 = (start, file, go)
    return list1
start = 1
while start == 1:
    # you need to get return value of function request
    list1 = request ()
    (start, file, go) = list1
    # Or you can simply write this way  (start, file, go) = request()
```

Comment: If you add some info about variable scope to this answer I'll upvote it.

Comment: Well, I meant some text in addition to the code to explain why the OP code didn't work, since answers with some explanatory prose tend to be considered more useful on SO than answers that are just a block of code. But I guess those comments do the job. :)